# How to upgrade Jquery to jquery1.4 in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to update jquery1.3.2 to jquery1.4 (in Asp.net MVC).

Please can anyone tell me step by step process for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the included js-File.
Worked for me without any problems.

Comment: Hmm ok.. Is that true once we upgrade the themas and styles for web page will change?
bec in 1.3.2 what ever the thems and styles we have will change once we upgrade to 1.4?
thanks